# Crear instalador online para evitar copias en Visual Studio

Tags: .net

Buen día..acabo de terminar una app de Windows forms en visual Studio 2019.

El caso es que quiero evitar que me copien el software..es decir usando click once si alguien se lleva el ejecutable setup.exe que esté genera puede instalar el software obviamente..pero se puede crear un instalador desde la nube? Por otro lado si alguien copia el ejecutable que se crea puede correr la app en otra máquina?

Comment: la respuesta es si a todo.. pueden hacer lo que quieran.. si queres seguridad anti copias, debes usar otros metodos...

Comment: Aunque hagas un instalador online, los archivos necesariamente tienen que estar en la computadora para ejecutarse. Lo que puedes ofrecer es software en la nube. No hay instalación pero demanda que un equipo corra el programa. Respondiendo a la última pregunta, varía de acuerdo a las dependencias que tenga y el sistema operativo.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Siempre hablando de software de escritorio: había visto una técnica que era lanzar una actualización y sino la descarga el programa no se inicia. Y al descargarla cambiarle la fecha de caducidad al programa o generar algún codigo

Comment: Es demasiado amplio como para una única respuesta. Podrías leer una dirección MAC de la PC autorizada y validar esa MAC en una BD en la nube, con lo cual podrán instalar el software, pero no utilizarlo (por ejemplo), pero hay infinitas respuestas y poca aclaración del alcance y las limitaciones que quieres imponer.